# Netbeans форматирование кода PHP + HTML

Tags: php, html, netbeans, форматирование

в Netbeans есть замечательная возможность форматирования кода, команда находится здесь: *Источник -> Формат (ALT+SHIFT+F)*

Это прекрасно форматирует код (HTML, PHP, CSS, JS ...), но только не **в случае мульти-языкового (PHP+HTML)** кода - в этом случае чаще всего форматирование **не дает хорошего результата**.

Пример кода: [здесь](http://yadi.sk/d/e_MFK2aT3QBZAB)

PHP+HTML это данность моей работы (работаю с CMS Bitrix).

Есть адекватное решение этой проблемы?

Comment: разделяйте код на соответствующие файлы.

Comment: Это один из шаблонов компонента CMS Bitrix, там так не получится. Посмотрите код и все станет ясно.

Answer (score 2):

Меня могут заминусовать, но я бы посоветовал использовать mvc что бы избежать месива в коде из php вставок тогда можно использовать конструкции `<?= $out_var ?>` и не делать в все в представлении.

Comment: Пример кода: yadi.sk/d/e_MFK2aT3QBZAB

Comment: Пока не могу посмотреть сейчас еду в автобусе

Comment: Ну как я и говорил, у тебя месиво из выборки, управления и отображения данных. Для начала нужно почитать про MVC

Answer (score 0):

Выделяй только форматируемую часть кода, и будет тебе счастье. А лучше почитай стилевые рекомендации, известные как PSR-0, PSR-1 и PSR-2.

Comment: Пример кода (чужой код, но с ним надо работать): yadi.sk/d/e_MFK2aT3QBZAB

Comment: тут вопрос о другом, нафиг вообще что-то форматировать, если ide делает это за тебя.

Comment: Этот код в Netbeans после форматирования во многих местах кривой, а форматирую я его ибо без форматирования он вообще ужасен (так был написан до меня).